# Should the Help Center include a definition of a "question"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, help

The Help Center includes definitions on [what type of questions should be posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what makes  a good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However, there is no definition on how a proper *question* is formulated. I'm referring here to the grammatical construct. I do realize that grammar is not a direct concern of this community but I do believe that such a specification could help.

I've seen many so called questions that actually were statements with a question mark at the end (e.g. "I need to make that but I'm new to ...?" or "Please help me to find the error?") I personally believe that a proper definition of a question would help, as it would increase both the quality of the questions asked and the quality of the users.

Should there be section in the Help Center where we could refer users that do not correctly understand the structure of a question?